# How to detect Android Emergency Call?

Tags: android

Briefly, I want to know if the user make an emergency call and get the call duration.

But:

1. Emergency call doesn't send outgoing call broadcast.
2. Many phones don't record emergency call log, I had test several phones, that's totally depends on the manufacturers. And the same manufacturer may have different strategy.

Observe the CallLog is a solution, but I want more coverage, what can I do?